# twig - pass function into template

Tags: php, function, inheritance, twig, template-engine

Currently I place my function in a class and pass an instance of this class into template and call my required function as a class method.

```
{{ unneededclass.blah() }}
```

I need to do like below

```
{{ blah() }}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I have a function blah(), how I pass it and call it in twig (using twig template syntax? )

Comment: What does this function do? I've only just started using Twig a few weeks ago, but I'm pretty sure you can't do this. If `blah()` modifies an existing variable, filters are the way to go.

Comment: It print out some html. Btw, thanks, I will stick my function into a class.

Comment: In that case, have you seen [macros](http://www.twig-project.org/book/02-Twig-for-Template-Designers)? (They are about halfway down the page) That might be just what you are looking for, and probably easier to implement than putting stuff in a class. I use them for easy form elements and links.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Update 5/14/2015

Commenters point out that I'm mostly wrong. If you really need a function, and not a filter or macro, you can do it as [suggested in the Twig docs](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#functions):

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('blah', function () {
   // ...
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

And use like

```
{{ blah() }}
```

---

In short, no, this is not possible.

However, hope is not lost!

#### Filters

If this function `blah()` of yours is meant to modify an existing variable, then it is a **filter**.

An example:

```
//in your PHP
function format_date($date_string,$format_string) {
    return date($format_string,strtotime($date_string));
}
$twig_env->addFilter('format_date',new Twig_Filter_Function('format_date'));

{# in your template #}
{{ some_date|format_date('n/j/Y') }}
```

(The first argument is the variable you are filtering, the second is supplied by normal means)

#### Macros

If, as you have indicated above, your function simply outputs HTML, then it is a good candidate for a **macro**.

An example:

```
{# in your template #}
{% macro say_hello() %}
<p>Oh! Hello, world!</p>
{% endmacro %}

{# ... later on ... #}
{{ _self.say_hello() }}
```

Or with parameters:

```
{% macro input(name,value,type) %}
<input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value }}">
{% endmacro %}

{{ _self.input('phone_number','867-5309') }}
{{ _self.input('subscribe','yes','checkbox') }}
```

#### Why?

The thing to remember is that Twig templates represent a **view**, in terms of MVC. This means they are isolated in terms of their environment, and can only represent the *context* you pass them via the data array you pass in the `$template->render()` method.

This is a good thing, as it decouples your presentation from your logic and data. If you can arbitrarily call functions, then you suddenly increase that coupling, which is a *bad* thing.

<strike>The other reason for this is the way PHP handles callbacks. Think about how you would have to pass that function into your template... Probably something like this:</strike>

```
function blah() {
    return "<p>Oh! Hello, world!</p>";
}

$template = $twig_env->loadTemplate('template.html');
echo $template->render(array('blah'=>'blah'));
```

<strike>In your template, the context variable `blah` is now just a string containing `'blah'`.</strike>

<strike>In vanilla PHP, when you use variable functions like this (try to use a string variable like a function), it (more or less) performs a lookup for that function, then calls it. You are *not* passing the function, just it's name.</strike>

<strike>The thing is, you cannot possibly pass a function into a template, because PHP's only mechanism for doing this is by name-string, and once inside a template, that name is no longer a function name and just a string.</strike>

A little bit long winded, but I hope that helps!

If you want more documentation, the official docs are [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html).

Comment: Twig also support functions, it's needed in some cases http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

Comment: forms are made with functions ,dude

Comment: "you cannot possibly pass a function into a template" -- you must have written this before closures existed.

Comment: @Mark: Holy crap, what was I thinking? Closures have been in since 5.3 in 2009. I'll update my answer to reflect this

Comment: This is no longer current. Twig_SimpleFunction has been deprecated. Now use TwigFunction.

Answer (score 7):

Although you cannot PHP callable directly, twig is extensible. You can add a callable filter, so you can apply to PHP functions passed to template.

```
namespace My\Twig\Extension;

class LambdaFilter extends \Twig_Extension {

    public function getName() {
        return 'lambda_filter';
    }

    public function getFilters() {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('call', array($this, 'doCall'))
        );
    }

    public function doCall() {
        $arguments = func_get_args();
        $callable = array_shift($arguments);
        if(!is_callable($callable)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }
        return call_user_func_array($callable, $arguments);
    }

}
```

Now if you pass variable `my_func` to template, you can do `my_func|call(arg1, arg2)`. You can even do higher order functions `"array_filter"|call(my_array, my_func)` and you can always do more things in filter like accepting array as parameters and so on.

Answer (score 6):

I was as lost as you were, my friend, but after searching the web for an answer and found none, I decided to see if I could do it myself. Therefore, I wanted to post my solution here (even though I know this post is old), because this is the first hit on google if you search for this problem.

Here it go, it is quite simple actually:

I made a class which contains my functions and variables, for example:

```
class functionContainer{
        function getRandomNumber()
        {
                return rand();
        }
}
$values = array(
'functions'=> new functionContainer()
);
```

So now we have $values as an array, which contains this object with a function "getRandomNumber()".

When rendering the template file, include this class as a value:

```
$twig->render('random.html', $values);
```

This way, inside the template file, you can just call this method to call the function and get your result:

```
{{ functions.getRandomNumber }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using [Anonymous class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php)

Create anonymous class in manager/controller/service ..

```
     $functions = new class($router)
    {
        public function __construct($router)
        {
            $this->router = $router;
        }

    public function getRowUrl(FileManager $fileManager)
    {
        if ($fileManager->isNode()) {
            return $this->router->generate('...', ['parent' => ...]);
        }
        return $this->router->generate('...', ['entity' => ...]);
    }
};
```

Paste parameter into view

```
$params=[
            'functions' => $functions

        ];



    return new Response($this->twig->render('...:index.html.twig', $params));
```

Use function in view

```
 {% set rowUrl = functions.rowUrl(entity) %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Full answer:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#id2

I prefer to use Twig Extension like this:

```
namespace Some\Twig\Extensions;

class MenuExtensions extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('sidebar_menu', [$this, 'generate_sidebar_menu']),
        );
    }

    public function generate_sidebar_menu($menu){
        return $menu;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'menu';
    }
}
```

In template:

```
{{ sidebar_menu('some text') }}
```

Comment: WARNING: \Twig_Function_Method is now deprecated and will be removed in 2.x