# twig template engine, using a static function or variable

Tags: php, templates, twig

Is there a way to call a static function or use a static variable in twig?

I have a class of static helper functions and want to use one or two in a template.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just passing variables or offering a function of your own to be used in templates?

Comment: I have a class of static helper functions so was hoping I could call them somehow without the need to add them using addFunction.

Comment: I think additionally, this is an interesting answer as well for you: [twig - pass function into template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595727/twig-pass-function-into-template/3595941#3595941)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Couple ways I've ended up doing it.

First is a function that can call a static function.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction('staticCall', new Twig_Function_Function('staticCall'));

function staticCall($class, $function, $args = array())
{
    if (class_exists($class) && method_exists($class, $function))
        return call_user_func_array(array($class, $function), $args);
    return null;
}
```

Can then be used like,

```
{{ staticCall('myClass', 'mymethod', [optional params]) }}
```

The other is to use a magic method.

Add the class to the render $context

```
$data['TwigRef']  = new TheClass();

class TheClass
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments) {
        return call_user_func_array(array('TheClass', $name), $arguments);
    }

    ...
}
```

Can then be used like,

```
{{ TwigRef.myMethod(optional params) }}
```

Probably best to add some extra checks so only approved functions call be called.

Comment: I've seen this before. I have yet to see a placement for it. Please, in a SF2 project, where is this code suppose to go? Where is $loader defined?

Comment: How to make this first solution work when you pass full class name with its namespace?

Comment: Good one. I suppose this is not meant to be in a symphony 2 project

Comment: I was working with Yii at the time but this should be easy to work into Symphony.

Comment: @AlexanderMorland see http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html effectively `$loader` should be defined in your application config that instantiates twig.

Comment: For implementing this in Symfony see the Extending Twig section of the cookbook for your version of Symfony. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: In php 5.6+ you can replace `call_user_func_array` with `return $class::$method(...$arguments);`

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add functions to your twig templates by registering them. Either they are already callable or you alias your static function by a name of it's own:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction('functionName', new Twig_Function_Function('someFunction'));
```

See the [**Functions** section in Extending Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/doc/advanced.html#functions).

Comment: Think I will need to make my own function so I can use static ones. somthing like static('class', 'function', [params])

Comment: Probably not, try to register `'class::function'`  as the `'someFunction'` parameter above and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: That's my problem, that might work, but then i would need to do it for every function i might need to use.

Comment: @Alex: Create another helper function that returns all functions to register in form of an array (key: name, value: callback), then just iterate over the array and automatically assign them. The helper class should know which helpers it offers, so you keep everything together.