# Laravel and Twig Bridge printing Auth object

Tags: php, twig, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel basic authentication but I am really struggling to use the Auth object in the views.

There are good examples using Blade, but I am using Twig (twig bridge) and cannot solve this.

I can `vardump(Auth::user()->name)` in my controller in regular php but how do I get the same in the twig file (my view file)?

How do I do something like;

```
{% if auth.guest %}
```

Or;

```
{{ Auth.user().name }}
```

I've tried so many different ways but just get nothing.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way twig works, accessing static variables /classes or static methods on classes is impossible without adding a function to the Twig Environment.

You can register a function like so:

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$twig->addFunction('staticCall', new Twig_Function_Function('staticCall'));

function staticCall($class, $function, $args = array())
{
    if (class_exists($class) && method_exists($class, $function))
        return call_user_func_array(array($class, $function), $args);
    return null;
}
```

Then i think you should be able to do:

```
{% if staticCall('Auth', 'guest') %}
    Hi there stranger, why don't you <a href="/login">login</a>?
{% endif %}
```

I took the code from this answer: [twig template engine, using a static function or variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844266/twig-template-engine-using-a-static-function-or-variable)

Comment: Could this help; https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge/blob/master/src/Extension/Laravel/Auth.php

Comment: Actually, yes. auth_guest would be the one! Also this could help too: https://github.com/rcrowe/TwigBridge/blob/master/src/Extension/Loader/Facades.php look at /config/twigbridge.php then extensions => facades, that should be the one, it's rather wel documented! TIL too! :-)

Comment: I'd say it's not well documented to someone who doesn't know what to do. I'd say it's horrible documentation. I have no idea how to use that. See my updates...

Comment: I have to agree with mike3875.  Trying to find that auth_user() is the function that I needed to use and not Auth.user() took me far too long.